# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 add in

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssms, visual-studio-addins, ssms-addin

I am trying to create a SSMS 2008 add in using the Visual Studio Add In project template with VS.NET 13. I have followed the instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073839/Create-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-Addin) from CodeProject. However, this tutorial is for SSMS 2012 and the folder structure is very different from SSMS 2008's folder structure. My question is: **Where should i put the .addin file to make SSMS 2008 use it?** 

Also, this is the registry key i have created

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\Addins\AddInName.Connect

Connect is the name of the class that provides logic for the addins connection with the host application. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.addin** file in not needed for SSMS 2008. The proper registry key you created and the corresponding CLSID registration should be enough.

This is what I used in my Tabs Studio add-in (msi, wix, current user installer):

```
  <Component Id="TabsStudioSSMS2008Component" Guid="986C2BFA-4C21-42e4-96B3-7C0178B841DC">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Sergey Vlasov\Tabs Studio\Installer">
      <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="SSMS2008" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>

    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\Addins\TabsStudio.Connect">
      <!--<RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="LoadBehavior" Value="3"/>-->
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="LoadBehavior" Value="[SSMS2008LOADBEHAVIOR]"/>
    </RegistryKey>

    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Classes\CLSID\{E52044B6-1EBA-4D82-AF2A-FABE2A79B106}">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="TabsStudio.Connect"/>
    </RegistryKey>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" 
                 Key="Software\Classes\CLSID\{E52044B6-1EBA-4D82-AF2A-FABE2A79B106}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" 
                 Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
    </RegistryKey>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Classes\CLSID\{E52044B6-1EBA-4D82-AF2A-FABE2A79B106}\InprocServer32">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="mscoree.dll"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ThreadingModel" Value="Both"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="TabsStudio.Connect"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Assembly" Value="TabsStudio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v2.0.50727"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="CodeBase" Value="[PersonalFolder]Visual Studio 2008\Addins\TabsStudio.dll"/>
    </RegistryKey>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Classes\CLSID\{E52044B6-1EBA-4D82-AF2A-FABE2A79B106}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="TabsStudio.Connect"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Assembly" Value="TabsStudio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v2.0.50727"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="CodeBase" Value="[PersonalFolder]Visual Studio 2008\Addins\TabsStudio.dll"/>
    </RegistryKey>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Classes\CLSID\{E52044B6-1EBA-4D82-AF2A-FABE2A79B106}\ProgId">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="TabsStudio.Connect"/>
    </RegistryKey>

    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Classes\TabsStudio.Connect">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="TabsStudio.Connect"/>
    </RegistryKey>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Classes\TabsStudio.Connect\CLSID">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="{E52044B6-1EBA-4D82-AF2A-FABE2A79B106}"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

Comment: So just create the registry key I have created and then place the add-in's .dlls in the Program Files(x86) folder? How will SSMS know where to find them?

Comment: @EndiZhupani Your CLSID CodeBase points to the actual dll. I've included sample code to the answer.

Comment: I think I managed to install it with a LoadBehavior = 1, but now when I open SSMS it fails to load the add in. The error message it displays is "No such interface supported" with an error number 80004002. Could it be that there is something wrong with the default interfaces in the Connect.cs?

Comment: @EndiZhupani The Connect class should have System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("myguid") and ComVisible(true) attributes attached.